# Display the same README.MD file in each folder?

Tags: github

Is there a way to display the same exact README.md file in each folder of a repository?

Can Github just always pull from the default (or top most level) readme.md file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a symlink to the root `README.md` in each folder.